# Angular i18n Translation outside template and more

Tags: angular, localization, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

I have a few questions about i18n implementation. After searching across documentation and across all the web, there are still some open issues for me.

1. Can I use a translate service from i18n to localize strings outside
   of templates? (aka ts files)
       In AngularJs there was
   **$translate** service for that purpose.
2. Is it possible to use i18n both **JIT** and **AOT**? it will be great to localize the static strings and let the dynamic ones to get
   translated on build time.
3. I already implemented localization with ngx-translate. Did someone use both ngx-translate and i18n in its projects?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for notice the confusion.
I would like to know how much it was efficient for that project using two methods of localization. There is nothing better than to learn from others' experience.

Comment: That's off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge,

Answer 1. yes we can use translate service from i18n to translate .ts files string but this is available from v9. Till version 8 .ts file translation is not present i suppose. Following link for support: [angular-localize](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/12/10/angular-localize/)

Answer 2. Yes, we can use i18n in both JIT and AOT mode. In AOT mode you are already creating application bundle per locale and as per user changes, you will load respective bundle. And in JIT mode you have to re-bootstrap the complete application after translating as per user choose locale.